# Using intern js how to configure selenium grid without localhost proxy

Tags: selenium-grid, intern

I am writing functional test case using intern.js. I wanted to run my test case in selenium grid which is already configured. I changed  tunnel: 'NullTunnel' and webdriver: {
            host:'',
            port: 4444
        }
In the intern configuration file and tried to execute my test case. I expect my testcase to be run on grid-config. But the intern is not running the testcase instead throws following error.

FATAL ERROR
Error: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session] connect ECONNREFUSED
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException  
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete]

Note: I did not run 'java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.x.jar -hub http://hub-server:4444/grid/register'  command because I don't want to use my local machine as proxy.

But I want intern-runner to run the testcase directly through selenium grid.
Please help me on how to configure this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution my self by adding tunnelOptions in the config with host and port information of the grid.

Thanks